# What happens when you call `append` on a list?

Tags: python, class, append, implementation

Firstly, I don't know what the most appropriate title for this question would be. Contender: "how to implement `list.append` in custom class".

I have a `class` called `Individual`. Here's the relevant part of the class:

```
from itertools import count
class Individual:
    ID = count()
    def __init__(self, chromosomes):
        self.chromosomes = list(chromosomes)
        self.id = self.ID.next()
```

Here's what I want to do with this class:

Suppose I instantiate a new individual with no chromosomes: `indiv = Individual([])` and I want to add a chromosome to this individual later on. Currently, I'd have to do:

```
indiv.chromosomes.append(makeChromosome(params))
```

Instead, what I would ideally like to do is:

```
indiv.append(makeChromosome(params))
```

with the same effect.

So my question is this: when I call `append` on a list, what really happens under the hood? Is there an `__append__` (or `__foo__`) that gets called? Would implementing that function in my `Individual` class get me the desired behavior?

I know for instance, that I can implement `__contains__` in `Individual` to enable `if foo in indiv` functionality. How would I go about enable `indiv.append(…)` functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`.append()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) is simply a method that takes one argument, and you can easily define one yourself:

```
def append(self, newitem):
    self.chromosomes.append(newitem)
```

No magic methods required.

Comment: Damn! I apparently got tunnel vision lol! Still, could you please explain what happens when I call `list.append`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: The list type (implemented in C) defines a method `.append()`, which is called by the interpreter; it expects one argument. The method adds the element to the list. Apart from being implemented in C, there is nothing magical about it.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Take a look at the source of the [`UserList` module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/UserList.py) which wraps a list in a custom class.