# What happens when we edit(append, remove...) a list and can we execute actions each time a list is edited

Tags: python, list

I would like to know if there is a way to create a `list` that will execute some actions each time I use the method `append`(or an other similar method).
I know that I could create a `class` that inherits from `list` and overwrite `append`, `remove` and all other methods that change content of `list` but I would like to know if there is an other way.
By comparison, if I want to `print` 'edited' each time I edit an attribute of an object I will not execute `print("edited")` in all methods of the `class` of that object. Instead, I will only overwrite `__setattribute__`.
I tried to create my own type which inherits of `list` and overwrite `__setattribute__` but that doesn't work. When I use `myList.append` `__setattribute__` isn't called. I would like to know what's realy occured when I use `myList.append` ? Is there some magic methods called that I could overwrite ?

I know that the question have already been asked there : [What happens when you call `append` on a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921222/what-happens-when-you-call-append-on-a-list). The answer given is just, there is no answer... I hope it's a mistake.

I don't know if there is an answer to my request so I will also explain you why I'm confronted to that problem. Maybe I can search in an other direction to do what I want. I have got a `class` with several attributes. When an attribute is edited, I want to execute some actions. Like I explain before, to do this I am use to overwrite `__setattribute__`. That works fine for most of attributes. The problem is `lists`. If the attribute is used like this : `myClass.myListAttr.append(something)`, `__setattribute__` isn't called while the value of the attribute have changed.

The problem would be the same with `dictionaries`. Methods like `pop` doesn't call `__setattribute__`.

Comment: `list.append` doesn't use any magic methods... it is the `append` method.  `__setattribute__` isn't even a magic method recognized by python. `__setattr__` is one but that is for setting attributes which has nothing to do with modifying a list.

Comment: So there is indeed no ways to do it...

Comment: I never said that ;) I'm thinking you can use a descriptor to notify your original object when a method is called on a (wrapped) attribute, I'm constructing an answer now.

Comment: Ok, thanks ! Unfortunately I have to leave now. I'll watch it tomorrow. thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would want something like `Notify_list` that would call some method (argument to the constructor in my implementation) every time a mutating method is called, so you could do something like this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):

        self.list = Notify_list(self.list_changed)
    def list_changed(self,method):
        print("self.list.{} was called!".format(method))

>>> x = Test()
>>> x.list.append(5)
self.list.append was called!
>>> x.list.extend([1,2,3,4])
self.list.extend was called!
>>> x.list[1] = 6
self.list.__setitem__ was called!
>>> x.list
[5, 6, 2, 3, 4]
```

The most simple implementation of this would be to create a subclass and override every mutating method:

```
class Notifying_list(list):
    __slots__ = ("notify",)
    def __init__(self,notifying_method, *args,**kw):
        self.notify = notifying_method
        list.__init__(self,*args,**kw)

    def append(self,*args,**kw):
        self.notify("append")
        return list.append(self,*args,**kw)
    #etc.
```

This is obviously not very practical, writing the entire definition would be very tedious and very repetitive, so we can create the new subclass dynamically for any given class with functions like the following:

```
import functools
import types

def notify_wrapper(name,method):
    """wraps a method to call self.notify(name) when called
used by notifying_type"""
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(*args,**kw):
        self = args[0]
        # use object.__getattribute__ instead of self.notify in
        # case __getattribute__ is one of the notifying methods
        # in which case self.notify will raise a RecursionError
        notify = object.__getattribute__(self, "_Notify__notify")
        # I'd think knowing which method was called would be useful
        # you may want to change the arguments to the notify method
        notify(name)
        return method(*args,**kw)
    return wrapper

def notifying_type(cls, notifying_methods="all"):
    """creates a subclass of cls that adds an extra function call when calling certain methods

The constructor of the subclass will take a callable as the first argument
and arguments for the original class constructor after that.
The callable will be called every time any of the methods specified in notifying_methods
is called on the object, it is passed the name of the method as the only argument

if notifying_methods is left to the special value 'all' then this uses the function
get_all_possible_method_names to create wrappers for nearly all methods."""
    if notifying_methods == "all":
        notifying_methods = get_all_possible_method_names(cls)
    def init_for_new_cls(self,notify_method,*args,**kw):
        self._Notify__notify = notify_method

    namespace = {"__init__":init_for_new_cls,
                 "__slots__":("_Notify__notify",)}
    for name in notifying_methods:
        method = getattr(cls,name) #if this raises an error then you are trying to wrap a method that doesn't exist
        namespace[name] = notify_wrapper(name, method)

    # I figured using the type() constructor was easier then using a meta class.
    return type("Notify_"+cls.__name__, (cls,), namespace)


unbound_method_or_descriptor = ( types.FunctionType,
                                 type(list.append), #method_descriptor,   not in types
                                 type(list.__add__),#method_wrapper, also not in types
                                )
def get_all_possible_method_names(cls):
    """generates the names of nearly all methods the given class defines
three methods are blacklisted: __init__, __new__, and __getattribute__ for these reasons:
 __init__ conflicts with the one defined in notifying_type
 __new__ will not be called with a initialized instance, so there will not be a notify method to use
 __getattribute__ is fine to override, just really annoying in most cases.

Note that this function may not work correctly in all cases
it was only tested with very simple classes and the builtin list."""
    blacklist = ("__init__","__new__","__getattribute__")
    for name,attr in vars(cls).items():
        if (name not in blacklist and
            isinstance(attr, unbound_method_or_descriptor)):
            yield name
```

Once we can use `notifying_type` creating `Notify_list` or `Notify_dict` would be as simple as:

```
import collections
mutating_list_methods = set(dir(collections.MutableSequence)) - set(dir(collections.Sequence))
Notify_list = notifying_type(list, mutating_list_methods)

mutating_dict_methods = set(dir(collections.MutableMapping)) - set(dir(collections.Mapping))
Notify_dict = notifying_type(dict, mutating_dict_methods)
```

I have not tested this extensively and it quite possibly contains bugs / unhandled corner cases but I do know it worked correctly with `list`!