# Tracing a list with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tkinter has these variable classes: `BooleanVar`, `DoubleVar`, `IntVar`, `StringVar`. All of them have a `trace()` method that allows you to attach a callback that is called when the variable changes.

Is it possible (or is there a workaround) to trace a list? Specifically, I'm looking for a way to monitor a list so that I can change the elements of a Treeview.

Comment: maybe a wrapper around the list is what you're after: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799938/what-happens-when-we-editappend-remove-a-list-and-can-we-execute-actions-e). I guess it still requires you to do some (heavy) lifting though....

Answer (score 1):

The code below includes a test function (forceChange) that can be deleted, but demonstrates the rest of the code traces a python list variable. Since you're already using the tk event loop, I used that, but I've also tested it using the sched and time modules to schedule events when there is no GUI.

```
from tkinter import * import sys

class ListManager:

    def __init__(self, root, listvar):
        self.root = root
        self.listvar = listvar
        self.previous_value = listvar.copy()
        # Create an event to watch for changes to the list.
        self.watch_event = root.after(20, self.watchList)
        # Create an event to change the list. This is for test purposes only.
        self.change_event = root.after(200, self.forceChange)

    def watchList(self):
        ''' Compare the previous list to the current list.
            If they differ, print a message (or do something else).
        '''
        try:
            if self.previous_value != self.listvar:
                print("Changed! Was:", self.previous_value, " Is:", self.listvar)
                self.previous_value = self.listvar.copy()
            # Reschedule this function to continue to check.
            self.root.after(20, self.watchList)
        except Exception:
            print("Variable has been destroyed")
            self.root.after_cancel(self.change_event)

    def forceChange(self):
        try:
            next = self.listvar[-1:][0]
        except:
            # Variable was destroyed.
            return
        if next == 11:
            sys.exit()
        next += 1
        self.listvar.append(next)
        self.root.after(500, self.forceChange)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    # This is the list we'll watch.
    mylist = [1, 2, 3]
    # Create a list manager
    vlist = ListManager(root, mylist)
    root.mainloop()
```